# Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired javax.net.ssl.SSLException: certificate_unknown when creating MobileFirst runtime

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I'm installing a v7.0.0 MobileFirst Server with Liberty 8.5.5.4 with Java 1.7.0 on RedHat in Nonadminstrator mode.  Steps I have followed:

1. Successfully install Liberty, create a server and verify it starts with no errors in messages.log.
2. Install MFP Server.
3. Use the MFP Server Configuration Tool to create an MFP configuration using the Liberty server.
4. Bounce the Liberty server and verify it starts with no errors.
5. Create an MFP Runtime using the Server Configuration Tool.
6. Bounce the server and observe SSL errors in the log.

The SSL errors seem to be related to Liberty trying to talk to the JMX REST client - at least that is my assumption since I haven't even invoked an adapter yet.

The WAR file I am using for the Runtime comes from a project that builds and runs fine in the MFP Studio Liberty development server.

The full log can be found at https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1frf7pjszm46n6/messages.log?dl=0, but here's the relevant error:

```
[8/4/15 18:23:09:400 CDT] 00000050 com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLHandshakeErrorTracker     E CWWKO0801E: Unable to initialize SSL connection. Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired. Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:6)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLEngineImpl.a(SSLEngineImpl.java:409)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLEngineImpl.a(SSLEngineImpl.java:469)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLEngineImpl.j(SSLEngineImpl.java:181)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLEngineImpl.b(SSLEngineImpl.java:176)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLEngineImpl.a(SSLEngineImpl.java:495)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:66)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:23)
at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:870)
at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLConnectionLink.readyInbound(SSLConnectionLink.java:531)
at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLConnectionLink.ready(SSLConnectionLink.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:906)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:929)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:796)
```

Comment: The error is an SSL issie - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown. 
at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:6). Maybe because the HTTPS port of the Liberty server is used by another server ?

Comment: Still waiting to hear from you.

Comment: Sorry, traveling this week and haven't had a chance to give this much attention.  I did take a quick look and do not see any port conflicts nor firewall issues.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  I went back to a system I knew worked and started looking for differences.  The configuration was all the same, but I noticed the working system used

```
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6470sr7fp1-20140708_01(SR7 FP1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20140627_204598 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR7_20140627_0924_B204598
JIT  - r11.b06_20140409_61252.04
GC   - R26_Java726_SR7_20140627_0924_B204598_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20140627_204598)
JCL - 20140707_01 based on Oracle **7u65-b16**
```

The system that was throwing the SSL errors was running

```
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6470sr6fp1ifix-20140220_01(SR6 FP1+IX90136+IX90137))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20140106_181350 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR6_20140106_1601_B181350
JIT  - r11.b05_20131003_47443.02
GC   - R26_Java726_SR6_20140106_1601_B181350_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20140106_181350)
JCL - 20140103_01 based on Oracle **7u51-b11**
```

I installed 7u65-b16 on the new system, restarted Liberty under that version of Java and all seems to be well now.

Comment: Thanks for the update. From the log it seem to be an issue with the SLL certificate of Liberty. Some errors say that the certificate is unknown (could be that the JCL is missing a cypher used by the certificate ?).  But line 2472 it says 'unable to find valid certification path to requested target' so could be a missing authority cert needed by the certificate.

Comment: Yes, these SSL errors threw me off for quite a while.  The resolution to the runtime startup issue was to upgrade to Java 7u65, but later I found that I got "No negotiable cyber suite" errors when my adapter tried to connect to a server over TLS 1.2.  Updated to Oracle Java 7u80 and that was resolved.

Comment: Hi @DSchultz_mo, could you provide more details about the solution ? I am facing the same issue. Do I need to uninstall something before ?

Comment: @William, I’m sorry but I ran into this issue over 5 years ago at another company and haven’t worked with MobileFirst Server since. I don’t really have any relevant context to give you, sorry.

Comment: @DSchultz_mo, Don't worry. Thanks for your reply.