# Apple Push Notification SSLHandshakeException

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

**Environment:**

1. Windows Server 2012 R2
2. JRE 1.8.0_101
3. IBM WAS Liberty Core 8.5.5.5
4. IBM MFP 7.1.0.00.20150913-2345

**APNS Port Enabled:**

1. gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
2. gateway.push.apple.com 2195

verified with telnet it is connecting.

iPhone build was tested with Eclipse studio it's works fine but the same pointed to remote server gives below error.

```
    [7/23/16 16:02:49:822 GST] 00000126 om.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl I Failed to send message Message(Id=2; Token=sdfsadfsdfsdfsdfsdf; Payload={"payload":"{\"tag\":\"Push.ALL\"}","aps":{"alert":{"action-loc-key":null,"body":"مرحبا كيف حالك اليوم؟"}}})... trying again after delay
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[7/23/16 16:02:49:838 GST] 00000125 om.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl I Failed to send message Message(Id=1; Token=sgaskjgsdkahdsfgksadhfgksdhfgsakdjfhgasdkhfds; Payload={"payload":"{\"tag\":\"Push.ALL\"}","aps":{"alert":{"action-loc-key":null,"body":"مرحبا كيف حالك اليوم؟"}}})... trying again after delay
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[7/23/16 16:02:51:501 GST] 00000125 om.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl E Couldn't send message after 3 retries.Message(Id=1; Token=sgaskjgsdkahdsfgksadhfgksdhfgsakdjfhgasdkhfds; Payload={"payload":"{\"tag\":\"Push.ALL\"}","aps":{"alert":{"action-loc-key":null,"body":"مرحبا كيف حالك اليوم؟"}}})
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[7/23/16 16:02:51:501 GST] 00000125 ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection E FPWSE1083E: Failed to send APNS notification with identifier 1, device token: sgaskjgsdkahdsfgksadhfgksdhfgsakdjfhgasdkhfds
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R Exception in thread "pool-5-thread-1" 
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.wrapAndThrowAsRuntimeException(Utilities.java:277)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:319)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000125 SystemErr                                                    R  ... 5 more
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 om.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl E Couldn't send message after 3 retries.Message(Id=2; Token=sdfsadfsdfsdfsdfsdf; Payload={"payload":"{\"tag\":\"Push.ALL\"}","aps":{"alert":{"action-loc-key":null,"body":"مرحبا كيف حالك اليوم؟"}}})
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection E FPWSE1083E: Failed to send APNS notification with identifier 2, device token: sdfsadfsdfsdfsdfsdf
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R Exception in thread "pool-5-thread-2" 
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.wrapAndThrowAsRuntimeException(Utilities.java:277)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:319)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
[7/23/16 16:02:51:516 GST] 00000126 SystemErr                                                    R  ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens due to Java version difference between the machines your server is installed on (dev vs prod). For example:

- [Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired javax.net.ssl.SSLException: certificate_unknown when creating MobileFirst runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821164/unauthorized-access-was-denied-or-security-settings-have-expired-javax-net-ssl-s)

Also could happen if not all ports are open, for example for the feedback service:

- feedback.push.apple.com, port 2196
  feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com on port 2196

Comment: feedback.push.apple.com, port 2196 feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com on port 2196 are accessible via telnet. Also, I would like to understand whether java version makes difference in Dev vs Prod. If that is true what version should I use because i have tried with JRE 7 & JRE 8. But still no luck. Exception that i am getting while I invoke Push notification but not while creating MFP Runtime